# Spacing issues with jQuery UI sortable plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've implemented the jQuery UI sortable plugin for an app I'm building. Users can upload an album of images and resort those images.

Here is a link to a short 15 sec screencast of the issue that's occurring.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xqp7h86cq6f7oa2/jquery-ui-sortable.mov

How can I alleviate the large margins being applied for spacing on the row of images? Or at least, reduce the amount of space when sorting images?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT* Here's a gist of the _form.html.haml file

https://gist.github.com/kbouw/a58e647b294918a74c33

Comment: Please provide the least amount of code that represents your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unsure if this is a limitation of the plugin or a value i've set in my code which is why the question is general, and includes a video displaying the issue. I'm adding a gist of my file if that helps.